# With min() in R return NA instead of Inf

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, min

Please consider the following:

I recently 'discovered' the awesome `plyr` and `dplyr` packages and use those for analysing patient data that is available to me in a data frame. Such a data frame could look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), # patient ID
                 diag = c(rep("dia1", 3), rep("dia2", 2)), # diagnosis
                 age = c(7.8, NA, 7.9, NA, NA)) # patient age
```

I would like to summarise the minimum patient age of all patients with a median and mean. I did the following:

```
min.age <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(min.age = min(age, na.rm = T))
```

Since there are `NAs` in the data frame I receive the warning:

```
`Warning message: In min(age, na.rm = T) :
no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`
```

With `Inf` I cannot call `summary(df$min.age)` in a meaningful way.

Using `pmin()` instead of `min` returned the error message:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :
 Column 'in.age' must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3
```

What can I do to avoid any `Inf` and instead get `NA` so that I can further proceed with:
`summary(df$min.age)`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `is.infinite()` to detect the infinities and `ifelse` to conditionally set them to `NA`.

```
#using your df and the dplyr package
min.age <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(min.age = min(age, na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(min.age = ifelse(is.infinite(min.age), NA, min.age))
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code does the following:

1. Splits the data frame into groups by `id`
2. Applies the `min` function within each group to the `age` variable, with the `na.rm=TRUE` option enabled.

So for `id` of `1` you get `min(c(7.8, NA, 7.9), na.rm=TRUE)`, which is the same as `min(c(7.8, 7.9))` which is just 7.8.

Then, for `id` of `2` you get `min(c(NA, NA), na.rm=TRUE)`, which is the same as `min(c())`.

Now, what is the minimum of an empty set of numbers? The definition of "minumum" is "a value smaller than all values in the set", and must satisfy the property that min(A) <= min(B) whenever B is a subset of A. One way to define the minumum of the empty set is to say it is "infinity", and that's how R treats the situation.

You can't really avoid getting `Inf` in this situation. But you could add another `mutate` to your chain to change any `Inf` to whatever you like, such as `NA`.

```r
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(min_age = min(age, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(min_age = ifelse(is.infinite(min_age), NA, min_age))
```

Answer (score 5):

an even simpler solution is the s function from the hablar package. It replaces empty vector with NA before evaluated in min/max. The code chunk by @awchisholm could be:

```
library(hablar)

min.age <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(min.age = min(s(age)))
```

*disclaimer* I am biased for this solution since I authored the package.

Answer (score 2):

```
(min.age <- df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(min.age = ifelse(all(is.na(age)),NA,min(age, na.rm = T))))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id min.age
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     7.8
2     2      NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `collapse::fmin`:

```
fmin(NA, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] NA
```

---

Note that `na.rm` defaults to `TRUE`, so `fmin` would suffice.

```
fmin(c(NA, 1, 2))
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered, but it is useful to point out that if the column in question is a Date or a datetime, then it will still appear to be an NA in the summary table, but actually isn't. This is doubly confusing! Consider:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-05-23", "", "2017-04-15", "", "")),
                 int = c(1L, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, NA),
                 group = rep(LETTERS[1:3],2))

s1 <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(min_date = min(date), min_int = min(int)) %>% mutate(min_date_missing = is.na(min_date), min_int_missing = is.na(min_int))
#> Warning: package 'bindrcpp' was built under R version 3.4.4
s2 <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(min_date = min(date, na.rm = TRUE), min_int = min(int, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% mutate(min_date_missing = is.na(min_date), min_int_missing = is.na(min_int))

df
#>         date int group
#> 1 2013-01-01   1     A
#> 2 2013-05-23   2     B
#> 3       <NA>  NA     C
#> 4 2017-04-15   4     A
#> 5       <NA>  NA     B
#> 6       <NA>  NA     C
s1
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   group min_date   min_int min_date_missing min_int_missing
#>   <fct> <date>       <dbl> <lgl>            <lgl>          
#> 1 A     2013-01-01      1. FALSE            FALSE          
#> 2 B     NA             NA  TRUE             TRUE           
#> 3 C     NA             NA  TRUE             TRUE
s2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   group min_date   min_int min_date_missing min_int_missing
#>   <fct> <date>       <dbl> <lgl>            <lgl>          
#> 1 A     2013-01-01      1. FALSE            FALSE          
#> 2 B     2013-05-23      2. FALSE            FALSE          
#> 3 C     NA            Inf  FALSE            FALSE

s1[[3,2]]
#> [1] NA
s2[[3,2]]
#> [1] NA

is.na(s1[[3,2]])
#> [1] TRUE
is.na(s2[[3,2]])
#> [1] FALSE

s1[[3,2]] == Inf
#> [1] NA
s2[[3,2]] == Inf
#> [1] TRUE

s1[[3,3]]
#> [1] NA
s2[[3,3]]
#> [1] Inf

is.na(s1[[3,3]])
#> [1] TRUE
is.na(s2[[3,3]])
#> [1] FALSE

s1[[3,2]] == Inf
#> [1] NA
s2[[3,2]] == Inf
#> [1] TRUE

sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2 dplyr_0.7.4   
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_0.12.17     utf8_1.1.3       crayon_1.3.4     digest_0.6.15   
#>  [5] rprojroot_1.3-2  assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         backports_1.1.2 
#>  [9] magrittr_1.5     evaluate_0.10.1  pillar_1.2.1     cli_1.0.0       
#> [13] rlang_0.2.0.9001 stringi_1.1.7    rmarkdown_1.9    tools_3.4.3     
#> [17] stringr_1.3.0    glue_1.2.0       yaml_2.1.18      compiler_3.4.3  
#> [21] pkgconfig_2.0.1  htmltools_0.3.6  bindr_0.1.1      knitr_1.20      
#> [25] tibble_1.4.2
```

Created on 2018-06-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 1):

This one seems interesting as it avoids the warning:

```
myMin <- function(vec) {
      ifelse(length(vec[!is.na(vec)]) == 0, NA_real_, min(vec, na.rm = TRUE))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to choose my own invalid value. Say `200` will be invalid value for `Age`.

Now one can twist the use of `min` function slightly. e.g. `min(age, 200, na.rm = TRUE)` . This ensure that age is shown as `200` instead of `+Inf` when all values are missing. The result on `df` will be:

```
min.age <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(min.age = min(age, 200, na.rm = T))

> min.age
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id min.age
#  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1  1.00    7.80
#2  2.00  200
```

Now, its up to programmer how they use/replace this invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can be used with `min`, but also `max` or `mean`, that avoids this problem, and makes it more generalizable:

```r
safe <- function(x, f, ...) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, f(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...))
```

For example:

```r
library(dplyr) 
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), # patient ID
                 diag = c(rep("dia1", 3), rep("dia2", 2)), # diagnosis
                 age = c(7.8, NA, 7.9, NA, NA), # patient age
                 age2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) # new column

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(age, age2), list(min = ~ safe(.x, min),
                                   max = ~ safe(.x, max),
                                   mean = ~ safe(.x, mean))))

     id diag    age  age2 age_min age_max age_mean age2_min age2_max age2_mean
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 dia1    7.8     1     7.8     7.9     7.85        1        3       2  
2     1 dia1   NA       2     7.8     7.9     7.85        1        3       2  
3     1 dia1    7.9     3     7.8     7.9     7.85        1        3       2  
4     2 dia2   NA       4    NA      NA      NA           4        5       4.5
5     2 dia2   NA       5    NA      NA      NA           4        5       4.5
```