# Return NAs instead of Inf when arguments of function are missing

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to add a column to a dataframe conditionally on another column.

Here is an example. I have a simple dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(time = seq(1,5,1), 
                 x = seq(1,5,1) + rnorm(n=5, sd=0.3))

> df
  time         x
1    1 0.8318573
2    2 1.9309468
3    3 3.4676125
4    4 4.0211525
5    5 5.0387863
```

I would like to add the `time` at which `x` exceeds a particular value (e.g., `x > 4`) to a new column, named `border_value`.

The following code does works:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(border_value = min(.[.$x > 4, "time"]))

> df
  time         x border_value
1    1 0.8318573            4
2    2 1.9309468            4
3    3 3.4676125            4
4    4 4.0211525            4
5    5 5.0387863            4
```

**Question**

I have a lot of dataframes, in which the values for `x` differ. Sometimes, the values do not exceed the `border_value` of `x>4`. In those cases, R generates an error:

> Warning message: In min(.[.$x > 4, "time"]) : no non-missing arguments
> to min; returning Inf

I would like to alter my code so that this error does not occur, and R puts NA's in the column instead. Any idea how to do this?

**Update**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342962/with-min-in-r-return-na-instead-of-inf) post, I was able to rewrite the code to:

```
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(border_value = ifelse(test = is.infinite(min(.[.$x > 7, "time"])), yes = NA, no = min(.[.$x > 4, "time"])))
```

This doesn't generate the `Inf`s, but still generates the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can write that. Here are a couple based on your use case,

```
df %>% mutate(border_value = which(x > 4)[1])
df %>% mutate(border_value = time[x > 4][1])
```

Both will return NA if no value is found